# I do not understand what is the support of the joint pdf of this question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with probability density function given by $f(x,y) = 6x Is(x,y)$, where $S = {(a,b) ∈ R+ : a + b \leq 1}$. Let
$$
U = X \,\,\text{ and }\,\, V = X + Y
$$
Note that the $R+$ above was written in the original question as $R^2+$, but I don't think the two is referencing a square. How should this $R^2+$ be interpreted?

a) Obtain the joint density function of the vector $(U,V)$
b) Obtain the conditional density function of U given $V = v,v ∈ (0,1)$. Obtain the $E(U/V=v)$ and the $\text{Var}(U/V=v)$.

According to this post that was already made on here:

[Joint pdf of two transformed variables ($W$ and $Z$) from joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784488/joint-pdf-of-two-transformed-variables-w-and-z-from-joint-pdf-of-x-and)

seems like I have to use the Jacobian transformation.

I am a bit confused as to what is the support of the joint pdf $6x Is(x,y)$ though. Can anyone help me out with this? Additionally, it general, I am pretty bad when it comes to figuring out supports especially if it wasn't explicitly given in the question. Can anyone give be a bit of advise about how to work out the support for joint pdf questions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^+ = [0,\infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}^+ = (0,\infty)$ depending on your definition. But for this task it doesn't matter which one you use.

So $${\mathbb{R}^+}^2 =  [0,\infty) \times  [0,\infty)$$

And then $f(x,y)$ is really a joint density due to $$\int_{{\mathbb{R}^+}^2} f(x,y) dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} 6x dy dx = 1$$

Comment: Hi @Gono, thanks for your response. First, R+ must be all positive real numbers, therefore this range goes from (0,∞). Correct? Can you walk me though how you got the support for y (0,1) and x (0, 1-x)?

Comment: Yes $\mathbb{R}^+$ is all positive real numbers OR all non-negative real numbers. Depends what you've defined.
You support is then $$S = \{(x,y), x \ge 0, y\ge 0, x+y \le 1\}$$ 
This gives $$x \in [0,1], y \in [0, 1-x]$$ or $$y\in [0,1], x \in [0,1-y]$$
I've chosen the first option.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok. Understood. Thanks for you help with this bro @Gono.